# @Resource not Injecting in Jar Classes from Lib Directory

Tags: cdi

I have a project with this structure:

```
WEB-INF/
WEB-INF/beans.xml
WEB-INF/classes/myclass.class
WEB-INF/lib/mylib.jar
              |
              +-----> com/libclass1.class
              +-----> com/libclass2.class
              +-----> META-INF/beans.xml
```

The CDI works fine among the classes inside the WAR (`myclass.class`), but any declaration of `@Inject` or `@Resource` from classes in `mylib.jar` return always null. I placed the `beans.xml` in both files but it continues returning null, what am I missing on this configuration? Any ideas?

I am trying to inject this resource:

```
@javax.annotation.Resource
UserTransaction tx;
```

But, if I use this code:

```
private UserTransaction tx;

public UserTransaction getTx() {
    if (tx == null) {
        try {
            tx = (UserTransaction) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return tx;
}
```

then it works from the Jar Classes. This code works because it is retrieving a *Predefined Bean*, but I am trying to make the `@Resource/@Inject` work with any other Resource/Class.

Comment: Do you set the jndi path when annotationg with @Resource?

Comment: @AdrianMitev, yes, I also tried that (`@Resource(name = "java:comp/UserTransaction")`) and does not work either. But if I inject `libclass1` into `myclass` it works, but injecting `libclass2` into `libclass1` does not work. The thing is that `jar`, nothing can be injected in the classes of the jar. Why?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Do you get unsatisfied dependency exception?

Comment: @AdrianMitev, no, it simply returns `null` at runtime.

Comment: How do you instantiate the class?

Comment: with `linclass1 lC = new libclass1()`, and should get injected `libclass2` or the `UserTransaction` resource.

Comment: Please add in the question the code showing how you are instantiating your classes.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the comments discussion, you are instantiating your classes alone:

```
libclass1 lC = new libclass1();
```

With this approach the CDI container is not aware of the class instantiation and cannot inject the dependencies for you.
What you have to do is:

- Inject an instance libclass1 in your caller so the CDI container can instantiate libclass1 and inject its dependencies there
- Manually instantiate libclass1 using the bean manager. Example of manual instantiation is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005982/get-only-in-service-cdi-managed-beans).

Comment: Yes, the classes need to be all wired up by `@Injetion`, so the CDI can be aware of all the classes to inject. But I wonder, then what are the scope annotation for if the CDI is not going to be aware of them until they are instantiated by another injection? It is clearly that no class can be injected by any other isolated class. The `@Resource` is not working in my case because the `class` is being created through Reflection, so no injection occurs for this.

Comment: CDI knows about the classes even because it scans the classpath. The point here that CDI has to instantiate your class (which happens using reflection) so it has the control over the instance in order to inject its dependencies. The purpose of the scope annotations are for CDI to know in which context (request, session, application, etc.) to look for the bean and if not found to instantiate it and put it there.

Comment: OK, the classes are all wired up by `@Inject`, and the Resources are still not injected. If you see the schema above, `myclass` can get Injected with `libclass1` and/or `libclass2`, but somehow `libclass1` cannot `@Inject libclass2`, returns null. Being `libclass1` first injected in `myclass`, so they are all in the CDI context.

Comment: You can't get null for @Inject if the bean instance is managed by CDI. You can get either the expected instance or exception at startup for unsatisfied dependency.

Comment: I said the very same thing, why isn't the CDI throwing an exception? I finally created mock empty classes with the same structure as the ones I am trying to implement the CDI, and they work just fine, all injections are made and resources attached. The original classes I am trying to Inject are quite complex and contain many methods and class instances, so there must be something in their implementation that is blocking the CDI from injecting the dependencies and return null. I think I'll keep these mock classes and transfer the functionality piece by piece until I find out the problem.